# How to wait until the src attribute is defined using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, tagname

I write a program with selenium in python.
My goal is to find the src of the video in the page. 
This is my code

```
video_element = chrome_driver.find_element_by_tag_name("video")
video_src = video_element.get_attribute("src")
```

When I try to check `video_src` I get an empty string, however if I put `time.sleep(1)` before I try to acquire the src I get the real link to the video.
I have tried to use `WebDriverWait` instead of `time.wait` like so

```
video_element = WebDriverWait(chrome_driver, 3).until(
            expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, "video"))
        )
```

But I couldn't find any condition that waits until the src tag is filled with the real link.
Is there a way to wait with selenium instead of time? (with time it is not guarantee that the src will be filled)

Comment: please provide your site or DOM

Comment: an example for a page in the site with a video is https://www.thewatchcartoononline.tv/www-working-episode-1-english-subbed. Notice that you have to switch to the frame of the video before you get the video element. Tell me if you require the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below solution before that you have to switch to iframe

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.thewatchcartoononline.tv/www-working-episode-1-english-subbed')
driver.switch_to.frame("anime-js-0")
video_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "video-js_html5_api")))
val = video_element.get_attribute("src")
print val
```

Output: 
[image]

Comment: I tried to do this before I switch and I got a timeout exception (because selenium could not found the video tag).
when I tried your solution after the switch, it did work but only if I used timeout=20, if I used timeout=3 it didn't work. this tells me that it acted just like time.sleep

Comment: I have encountered the same problem as before, please check your code with timeout=3 not 20, also you didn't use the chrome_option you created, did you mean to do that?

Comment: I have removed  chrome_option and changed WebDriverWait to 3 still its working fine for me. please check updated solution

Comment: You are correct, I forgot to change the locator to be with id and not tag name

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the below.

```
video_element = WebDriverWait(chrome_driver, 3).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//video[not(@src='')]"))
        )
```

Comment: It didn't work, do you care to explain about the xpath you used?

Comment: wait until the `video` element which have `src` attribute value which is not equals to `""`.

Comment: it seems like it suppose to work, I have no idea why it doesn't. did you check it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

To extract the value of the *src* attribute you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "video"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//video"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```